# can't install locales HELP

Tags: locale, perl, dpkg

When trying to solve this problem here 
How to fix perl : warning : setting local failed
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990851/how-to-fix-perl-warning-setting-local-failed-on-raspberry-pi?noredirect=1#comment51889438_31990851](http://How%20to%20fix%20perl%20:%20warning%20:%20setting%20local%20failed)

i run

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        LC_PAPER = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "fr_FR.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
dpkg-query: package 'locales' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: locales is not installed
```

so i run this command to install locales

> sudo apt-get install locales

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2-mpm-prefork : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u5) but it is not going to be installed
 apache2.2-common : Depends: apache2.2-bin (= 2.2.22-13+deb7u5) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: apache2-utils but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: procps but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: ssl-cert but it is not going to be installed
 libbz2-1.0 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19)
 libcomerr2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libdb5.1 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc1 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libgssapi-krb5-2 : Depends: libkeyutils1 (>= 1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libkrb5support0 (>= 1.12~alpha1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                    PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libk5crypto3 : Depends: libkeyutils1 (>= 1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libkrb5support0 (>= 1.12~alpha1+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
                PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libkrb5-3 : Depends: libkeyutils1 (>= 1.5.9) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libkrb5support0 (= 1.12.1+dfsg-19) but it is not going to be installed
             PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libmagic1 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libpcre3 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libssl1.0.0 : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                        debconf-2.0
               PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
 libxml2 : Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but it is not going to be installed
           PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: xml-core but it is not going to be installed
 locales : Depends: glibc-2.13-1
           Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                    debconf-2.0
 php5-common : Depends: sed (>= 4.1.1-1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: psmisc (>= 22.15-1~) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: lsof but it is not going to be installed
               PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1~) but it is not going to be installed
 tzdata : Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) but it is not going to be installed or
                   debconf-2.0
 ucf : Depends: debconf (>= 1.5.19) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: coreutils (>= 5.91) but it is not going to be installed
 zlib1g : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

i neeed some help please

Comment: Have you recently run ( sudo) apt-get update and apt-get upgrade?

Comment: @joan yes !!! i run them a lot because every time i install some new packages and recently i installed mongodb

Comment: Perhaps it is a temporary repository problem.  It happens sometimes.  Have you installed any non-repository software?

Comment: Edit in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @joan No i don't think so

Comment: @goldilocks => what's should i edit in the file ??  deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi  
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://apt.adafruit.com/raspbian/ wheezy main

Comment: Try commenting out that adafruit one temporarily.

Comment: @goldilocks commenting adafruit haven't solve anything , must  i reboot to take effect ?

Comment: No.  It's the only unusual thing I see in that.   I have seen this problem here before though.  Debian `apt` can be a real jerk of a package manager.  You might try asking how to resolve stuff like this on [U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), I don't know because I've never had quite this problem.  Just say you are using Raspbian and skip the first part, start with the bit about *"apt-get install locales"*.

Comment: @goldilocks ok, i have put it here because i have found that it's has something to do with ** ssh ** since i am using an ssh session to connect to the pi from the laptop :  `ssh pi@10.42.0.12` , sorry i forgot to mention it !!!

Comment: `ssh` isn't unique to the pi and it shouldn't matter to `apt`.   The errors certainly don't look like that would cause them anyway; there's no network issue indicated.  It's because it's gotten screwed up some how and ended up in an inconsistent state.